# install4j default options on update installation in welcome screen

Tags: install4j

In install4j welcome screen, if there is a previous installation, the welcome screen may be like below:

The default choice is "Yes, update the existing installation" on the welcome screen.

Is it possible to make "No, install into a different directory" as default choice when launching welcome screen?

Since I have no enough reputation, I can not attach a picture here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the default selection is not possible, but you can disable the "Alert for update installation" property on the "Welcome" screen.

Comment: Maybe my requirement is a little rare. Thanks a lot!